# How to compare and remove common objects( NSDictionaries) from 2 NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two NSMutableArrays, filled with dictionary objects, like

```
NSMutableArray * bigArray = @[dictionary1,dictionary2,dictionary3];
NSMutableArray * smallArray = @[dictionary1];
```

I want to remove the common elements (dictionay1) from the big array

Note: small array is subset of big array and elements are distinct

Comment: What would you do if you had `@[A, B, C, B]` and `@[C, D]`? (Note that there are both duplicates and out of order objects as well as objects in the smaller array that doesn't exist in the larger (so it's no a true subset))

Comment: just compare big array with small one using if condition/ for-loop then remove the object if found same else do nothing.

Comment: In my problem smaller dictionary would by its design a sub-part of bigger dictionary

Comment: that would be iterating each object and then comparing dictionary values??

Comment: @carelesslyChoosy so what about duplicates and out of order objects? What would you do with `@[A, B, C, B]` and `@[C, B]` and what would you do with `@[A, B, C, B, B]` and `@[B, B]`?

Comment: No not possible, each elements are distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[bigArray removeObjectsInArray:smallArray];
```

removes all objects in `bigArray` that are contained in `smallArray`.

Comment: Sir, Does it matter if object is an nsstring or nsdictionary or a custom object?

Comment: @carelesslyChoosy: It works with all kinds of objects. It uses `isEqual:` to compare the objects. For strings and dictionaries, `isEqual:` compares the *contents* of the objects. For custom objects, `isEqual:` simply compares the *pointers* (the address), but you can override it in your custom class.

Answer (score 1):

If each element is distinct (as you say in the comments) then you can filter the array using a predicate that removes all the objects that inside of the smaller subset. Since you are using an array in your question, I assume that the order of the objects matter.

*If you need to preserve the order, then you will need to filter the array. Converting to a set will break the order (unless you are able to resort it afterwards.*

You are using mutable arrays in your question, so I will do the same. Just be aware that the original array is actually modified:

```
NSMutableArray *original = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"A", @"E", @"C", @"B", @"D"]];
NSMutableArray *subset   = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"C", @"B"]];

NSLog(@"before : %@", original);

[original filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    // return YES for objects to keep
    return ![subset containsObject:evaluatedObject];
}]];

NSLog(@"after : %@", original);
```

The output of this code is:

```
before : (
    A,
    E,
    C,
    B,
    D
)
after : (
    A,
    E,
    D
)
```

You can see that the order is preserved.

---

If you don't want to modify the original array you can produce a new filtered array instead. The small difference is that you call `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` instead of `filterUsingPredicate:`. The predicate is the same:

```
NSArray *filtered = [original filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    // return YES for objects to keep
    return ![subset containsObject:evaluatedObject];
}]];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSSet is perfect class to do this kind of job. Try that;

```
NSMutableSet *bigSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:bigArray];
[bigSet minusSet:[NSMutableSet setWithArray:smallArray]];
bigArray = [[bigSet allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

The thing worth to point is that if your array will store duplicate and you convert it to NSSet the duplicate will be removed in that case you shouldn't use it. The second thing is it can change order of the elements in your array.

Comment: Except if order matters.