# Compare objects in two Collections

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, collections

I have the following scenario:

I have two collection classes (could be `NSArray`, `NSMutableArray`, `NSSet`, `NSOrderedSet` or whatever would be best suited for this case), which hold unique objects of the same type (unique in the sense that for all objects in the collections for no two elements the `isEqual` method would return `true`).

Lets say the first collection instance holds the following objects `(1,2,3,4,5)` and the second one `(2,3,4,6,7)`. Now I need a method that returns the difference between the two collections, with the extra info what exactly the difference from each collection was.
An example result for the example would be: `(1,5) was removed from the first collection and (6,7) added two the second collection`.

I know if I use the `NSMutableArray` with a sorted list and decide which list has more elements than the other, I could use `removeObjectsInArray` to get a list of the different objects (like described in [Compare two arrays with the same value but with a different order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709494/compare-two-arrays-with-the-same-value-but-with-a-different-order/15710166#15710166) or in [How to compare and remove common objects( NSDictionaries) from 2 NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907650/how-to-compare-and-remove-common-objects-nsdictionaries-from-2-nsmutablearray)), but don't really know which objects was in which collection. I could create a temporary collection and put the result of `removeObjectsInArray` in that array and compare the other two initial arrays with the temporary array. Seems little verbose though. Is there a better way that I don't know of?

Comment: Does order matter? In other words, if the second array is `4,3,2,7,6`, would the answer be different?

Comment: No, order should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much slicker way for you to do what you want by using NSPredicate. When I run the following code:

```
NSArray *firstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7", nil];
NSArray *secondArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"8",nil];

NSArray *itemsMissingFromSecondArray = [firstArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT SELF IN %@", secondArray]];
NSArray *itemsMissingFromFirstArray = [secondArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT SELF IN %@", firstArray]];

NSLog(@"itemsMissingFromFirstArray=%@\nitemsMissingFromSecondArray=%@", itemsMissingFromFirstArray, itemsMissingFromSecondArray);
```

I get the following output showing what was missing from each array that was in the other array:

```
itemsMissingFromFirstArray=(
    8
)
itemsMissingFromSecondArray=(
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7
)
```

Less code than sorting and merging, doesn't use a bunch of temporary arrays, and simple enough to read.

NOTE: If someone also wants to know the items that are in both arrays, the solution is similarly simple:

```
NSArray *itemsFoundInBothArrays = [firstArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", secondArray]];
```

Comment: In fact I do like this solution! It has a functional programming flavor to it and reminds me of Haskell. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSArray *) removeObjectsFromArray :(NSArray *)arrayToRemoveFrom thatAreAlsoIn:(NSArray *)arrayOfItemsToRemove
{
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayToRemoveFrom];
    [newArray removeObjectsInArray:arrayOfItemsToRemove];    
    return newArray;
}

+(void) findArrayDifferences
{
    NSArray *bigArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7", nil];
    NSArray *smallArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"8",nil];

    NSArray *itemsInBigArrayThatAreNotInSmallArray = [self removeObjectsFromArray:bigArray thatAreAlsoIn:smallArray];

    NSArray *itemsThatAreInBothArrays = [self removeObjectsFromArray:bigArray thatAreAlsoIn:itemsInBigArrayThatAreNotInSmallArray];

    NSArray *itemsInSmallArrayThatAreNotInBigArray = [self removeObjectsFromArray:smallArray thatAreAlsoIn:itemsThatAreInBothArrays];

    NSLog(@"itemsInBigArrayThatAreNotInSmallArray=%@\nitemsThatAreInBothArrays=%@\nitemsInSmallArrayThatAreNotInBigArray=%@", itemsInBigArrayThatAreNotInSmallArray, itemsThatAreInBothArrays, itemsInSmallArrayThatAreNotInBigArray);
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
itemsInBigArrayThatAreNotInSmallArray=(
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7
)
itemsThatAreInBothArrays=(
    1,
    2,
    3
)
itemsInSmallArrayThatAreNotInBigArray=(
    8
)
```

Comment: `removeObjectsInArray` is a `void` function.

Comment: Sorry for the rushed answer. I updated it to be a working example though I realize you may not want to use temporary arrays.

Comment: See my other answer for a much slicker solution that I think you will like.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to know the difference, you can make use of NSMutableSet and the minusSet function.

```
 [set1 minusSet:set2];
```

will give you the elements in set1 but not in set2 straight away. So you don't need any temp collection and compare with original collection again.

Otherwise, if you only want to remove the elements, you can make use of NSArray and do sth like:

```
 [secondArray removeObjectsInArray:firstArray];
```

Edited:
To find all the diff in one shot:

```
 [ [set1 unionSet:set2] minusSet: [set1 intersectSet:set2] ];
```

Comment: The problem with `minusSet` is the same as `removeObjectsInArray`, you only get the difference from one set/array, but not from both. `minusSet` is basically `removeObjectsInArray` for the `set` collection.

Comment: Edited the answer. I think you can do it in one line like this.

Comment: I really appreciate that you are trying to help, but your answer is wrong at many points. For example `unionSet` and `intersectSet` are both `void` functions, thus using `minusSet` won't event work. I can see what you are trying to do, but then I would need several temporary sets and even then I only get a union of both differences and still don't know which collection was lacking which object.